# How to find out if insertion or update occured in mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following code in my node.js application where I either update a field or insert a new entry:

```
 DocPrivilege.update({
                _id: {
                    $in: user.documentsPriv
                }
            }, {
                $set: {
                    access: parseInt(req.body.access),
                    documentName: req.body.documentName,
                    documentId: req.body.documentId
                }
            }, {
                upsert: true
            }, function(err, updated) {
                if (err || !updated) console.log("User not updated");
                else {
                    console.log("User updated");
                }
            });
```

Is there a way how I can differentiate if an update or an insertion occured?

Comment: More specifically the second answer is node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `db.getLastError()`.

It gives you an object with several properties. The property "n" gives you the number of documents updated.

[Here's](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getLastError/#dbcmd.getLastError) some documentation about it, and [here's](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#lasterror) an example of getLastError in node.js